# Is there a way to create a chain of views in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I want to create a chain of views in SwiftUI, I was using `NavigationView` but was deprecated, are there some alternatives in iOS 16.0?

view1 -> view2 -> view3 -> view4 -> root(view3)

[image]

```swift
enum Screens {
    case view1
    case view2
}

extension Screens: Hashable {}

final class SettingsNavigationManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var screen: Screens? {
        didSet {
            print(" \(screen)")
        }
    }
    
    func push(to screen: Screens) {
        self.screen = screen
    }
    
    func popToRoot() {
        self.screen = nil
    }
}

struct viewOne: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settingsNavManager: SettingsNavigationManager
    var body: some View{
        Button("Go to ViewTwo") {
            settingsNavManager.push(to: .view2)
        }
        .background(
            NavigationLink(
                destination: viewTwo(),
                tag: .view2,
                selection: $settingsNavManager.screen) { EmptyView() }
        )
    }
}
```

I have read about NavegationStack but idk, it's like to implements list and details items.

Comment: A `NavigationStack` is exactly what you should use. What problem did you encounter when you are using it? Please elaborate.

Comment: oh thanks @Sweeper :D so I'm going for good road, some tip for return the root of the NavigationStack ?

Comment: You can use [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/init(path:root:)-63x0h) and pass a binding of `NavigationPath`. Set the binding to an empty navigation path when you want to pop to the root. Please show a [mcve] of the problem to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

you can just use navigationPath object in your model which will manage push and pop for you.

I want to create a chain of views in SwiftUI, I was using NavigationView but was deprecated, are there some alternatives in iOS 16.0 ?

view1 -> view2 -> view3 -> view4 -> root(view3)

enter image description here

> enum Screens { case view1 case view2 }
>
> extension Screens: Hashable {}
>
> final class SettingsNavigationManager: ObservableObject {
> @Published var path: NavigationPath }

then you initialize navigationstack with

> NavigationStack(path: $settingsNavManager.path){  }

Then you can use

> settingsNavigationManager.path.append()

and

> removeLast(settingsNavManager.path.count)

as push and popToRoot

you can also use navigationdestination to adjust which view should be called according to your screens enum

> .navigationDestination(for: Screens.self){ screen in
> switch screen{
> } }